# bibliography file error using apa

Tags: bibliographies, apa-style

I have searched for hours trying to find a solution.

I have compiled pdf to `latex` then `bibtex` then `latex` using texworks and this is the result

```
! Argument of \astroncite has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.82 ...rsts is reported by others.  \cite{McNabb}
                                                   conclude that for a data ...
?
```

I have `\include*` files but have commented them out to no effect.  I am using `\bibliographystyle{apa}` and `\usepackage{natbib}`.

Here is some of the .bib file

```
@article{blind,
 author = {Newstead, Stephen E. \& Dennis, Ian},
 year = {1990}, 
 title = {BLIND MARKING AND SEX BIAS IN STUDENT ASSESSMENT},
 journal = {Assessment \& Evaluation in Higher Education},
 volume = {15},
number = {2},
 pages = {132-139},
 doi = {10.1080/0260293900150204},
URL = {link},
 eprint = {link}
}

@article{BRW,
author = {Barrow, Michael and Reilly, Barry and Woodfield, Ruth},
title = {The determinants of undergraduate degree performance: how important is gender?},
journal = {British Educational Research Journal},
volume = {35},
number = {4},
pages = {575-597},
year = {2009},
doi = {10.1080/01411920802642322},
URL = {link},
eprint = {link}
}

@article {McNabb,
author = {McNabb, Robert and Pal, Sarmistha and Sloane, Peter},
title = {Gender Differences in Educational Attainment: The Case of University Students in England and Wales},
journal = {Economica},
volume = {69},
number = {275},
pages = {481-503},
year = {2002}, 
publisher = {Blackwell Publishers Ltd.},
issn = {1468-0335},
url = {link},
doi = {10.1111/1468-0335.00295},
eprint = {link}
}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I second Johannes_B's request for a MWE.  Your posted `bib` file compiles fine a minimal document, so the problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: I've just tested your fragment with biber and biblatex (apa style): it compiles fine. So the problem must be elsewhere really. Could you give a minimal (non-)working example?

Comment: You should use `and` and not `\&` to separate authors in an `author` field.

Comment: Your write-up is a bit confusing: The error message you provide says something about `\astroncite`, yet the `natbib` package (which you say you load) does not provide such a command. Are you maybe loading additional packages that provide citation commands (such as `\astroncite`)?